# Raytheon JAN-6080WB Vacuum Tube question

Tags: vacuum-tube

I found this and several more, inside a old ocilloscope, I found the data sheet on it.

6.6 v, pins 7, 8, are the heater pins, but when i put power on it, i do not get a glow. are pins 7 and 8 where i put one + or - connection and somewhere else the power completes the circut. It is my first time messing with a vacuum tube.

tested with my meter, and it chrips away to tell me there is connection. i have even visually inspected under my 10x magnifyer, and there are no broken connections.

what am i doing wrong? why will it not glow? its for a prop project for my brother.

Comment: What are you using to power it?

Comment: 0-12v makeshift variable power supply.. i hacked it together using xbox PSU, atari 1MEG pot, variable resistor for the multimeter hacked into it to read the voltage..and some extended wire propes with bananna clips on it, so i can hook up probes, or dragon clips to it..

Comment: Are you sure it can supply 2.5A?

Answer (score 3):

According to a datsheet I found, pins 7 and 8 are the heater pins.  The heater requires 6.3 volts at 2.5 Amp.

The heater will only be visible at the top and bottom of the plate assembly - it may not make a very good prop for you.

Comment: Well its not the main focus, but i wanted to generate a decent glow off it, just not a lot...the main focus of the prop is a LED lit power cell, the vacuum tube is for a more retro look, it is sopposed to be a fallout 4, radioactive powercell charger. the power cell comes out... the tube is just there to dim glow to pretend say..its working..but its not producing even a small glow what so ever even in pitch black i cant see anything.

Comment: It's a long, long time since I worked with 6080s, but I'd expect at least two small spots of orange glow at the top of the element assembly if you are applying sufficient current to the heater pins.

Comment: My 12AT7WA lights up, my JAN 5664 too, so i applied 12v to this trouble one, and a dim glow comes ushering forth..i think maybe its just becasue is massive thing is as big as my hand.  but the glow comes right where you said it would, and it decent enough.

Comment: Beware!  The rated voltage for the 6080 heater is 6.3 volts - 12 volts may burn it out fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the heater is to heat the cathode.  Visible light is a side effect.  Some tubes you can hardly find a glow regardless of the view angle, some you can see readily.

Here's what you can do to get that effect you are looking for:  Take a flat file and file off the end of the indexer (the plastic piece sticking out the bottom of the tube in the middle) so that you can look into the bottom of the tube and see the glass.  Stick the tube in the socket.  Glue a bright LED of your choicest color (I use pink) into the hole.  The LED will illuminate the interior of the tube from below and look waaaay cool.  This is what I do for my guitar amps (I don't glue the LED to the bottom of the tube, I fabricate a spring-loaded housing for the LED, but you don't need to worry about tube replaceability).  Check out the pictures on my site: http://cuamps.com/pargo.html

Comment: Yes i saw something about this. I was thinking to do it. but keep the tube in tack in case i want to use it for its real purpose.

Comment: Filing off the bottom of the indexer does not affect the operation of the tube, should you want to use it in the future.  Use something temporary, maybe a spot from a glue gun, to glue the LED in if you want to be able to remove it easily.

Is  Mr. Bennett's or my answer going to work for you?